# Percona server 5.7 centos 6.8 server not starting with log-bin option

Tags: mysql, centos6, percona

I am struggling starting my percona server 5.7 on my centos 6.8 VPS with log-bin, log_bin_basename option.
server works fine without bin log options and if i add them in my my.cnf (actually percona-server.conf.d/mysqld.cnf, default my.cnf includes this file) server start fails without putting anything in log-error (/var/log/mysqld.log) file.

Below is my contents of cnf file (percona-server.conf.d/mysqld.cnf).

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
# BINARY LOGGING #
log-bin=/var/log/mysql/bin-mysql
expire-logs-days=15
sync-binlog=1
log_bin_trust_function_creators=on
binlog_format=MIXED
```

I have also tried below changes but no success.

---

```
log_bin=ON
log_bin_basename=/var/log/mysql/bin-mysql
```

---

```
log_bin=1
log_bin_basename=/var/log/mysql/bin-mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write add
 `server-id=1` 
line config file.

Comment: kindly consider adding more information in your answer for easier understanding